# JPanel overdraws overlapping JComcoBox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, drawing

I'm writing a small "Game" in Java, in which I am using a **JPanel** as the main rendering screen.
I've also included a **JComboBox** above the rendering-JPanel for dropdown-options. But when I try to expand the JComboBox it gets **overdrawn** from the JPanel.

I've tried **setComponentZOrder()** but this only made the Component eat each other in the LayoutManager. And **JLayeredPane** didn't seem to work either.

How can I make a *"realtime redered"* JPanel not overdraw overlapping components?

Simplified example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel renderScreen = new JPanel();
    Thread drawingThread = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            Graphics graphics = renderScreen.getGraphics();
            graphics.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, renderScreen.getWidth(), renderScreen.getHeight());

            try {Thread.sleep(5);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        }
    });
    frame.add(renderScreen, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JComboBox<String> dropdown = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Hello", "StackOverflow", "please", "help"});
    frame.add(dropdown, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.setComponentZOrder(renderScreen,1);
    frame.setComponentZOrder(dropdown,0);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    drawingThread.start();

}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: That's not how you should be doing Swing Graphics or threading. The code is breaking several Swing rules.

Comment: Ok, can you point me to a guide how to make it right. I've only seen the "overload paint()" method, but this does not refresh in the high interval that need. Or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: `Thread drawingThread = new Thread(() -> {` ... no, no a thousand times no.  `Graphics graphics = renderScreen.getGraphics();` no, no a thousand times no. *"I've only seen the "overload paint()" method, but this does not refresh in the high interval that need"* - Override `paintComponent` and do your custom painting there, then use a Swing `Timer` to trigger repaints.  Not sure why you need to clear the background every 5 milliseconds, but I guess that's an out of context snippet.

Comment: thank you, thank you, a thousand times thank you. finally I've got pointed in the right direction in this issue! It works

Comment: I recommend The Java™ Tutorials: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) (and other [sections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is breaking several Swing rules, including:

- Don't use getGraphics on a component to get a Graphics object. That object will be short lived and may be null at some point.
- Don't make Swing calls from within a background thread or any other non-Swing event dispatch thread.

Instead,

- use a Swing Timer to drive the animation,
- do drawing within the paintComponent method.
- be sure to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method in your paintComponent override so that housekeeping painting can be done
- Note that one should override the paintComponent method of a JPanel (or other object that extends from JComponent) and not override the paint method, since for one, paintComponent gives you double buffering by default, making animation smoother.

For example

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingGui01 extends JPanel {
    private JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"});
    private AnimationPanel animationPanel = new AnimationPanel();

    public SwingGui01() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(comboBox, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(animationPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing GUI 01");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new SwingGui01());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

class AnimationPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int DELTA_X = 5;
    private static final int DELTA_Y = DELTA_X;
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = 300;
    private static final int ANIMATION_DELAY = 20;
    private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.MAGENTA;
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private int deltaX = DELTA_X;
    private int deltaY = DELTA_Y;

    public AnimationPanel() {
        setBackground(BACKGROUND);
        Timer timer = new Timer(ANIMATION_DELAY, e -> {
            if (y > getHeight() - 50 ) {
                deltaY = -DELTA_Y;
            } else if (y < 0) {
                deltaY = DELTA_Y;
            }
            if (x > getWidth() - 50) {
                deltaX = -DELTA_X;
            } else if (x < 0) {
                deltaX = DELTA_X;
            }
            x += deltaX;
            y += deltaY;
            repaint();
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: finally it works!